# how to compile string(contains angular dir) before appending into html in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is the code of `html` and `jquery` that used to generate invoice automatically. here I displayed total amount by `qnty*rate` but if I passed it by `jquery` then I have to compile `angular` because I know I have to compile it before doing this, but how can I compile it in `jquery`?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">Description of Goods</td>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">HSN CODE</td>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">QTY</td>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">Units</td>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">Rate</td>
    <td class="tg-9hbo">AMOUNT (INR)</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="products" ng-app="">
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="number" ng-model="qty"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="number" ng-model="rate"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{qty * rate}}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <button class="addp">Add New Product</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">TAX<br>GST <input type="number">%</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">18%</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">718.2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">GRAND TOTAL</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">4708</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var tbl = '<tr class="products1" ng-app="">'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1"><input type="text"></td>'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1"><input type="text"></td>'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1"><input type="number" ng-model="qty1"></td>'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1"><input type="text"></td>'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1"><input type="number" ng-model="rate1"></td>'+
            '<td class="tg-yw4l1">{{qty1 * rate1}}</td>'+
          '</tr>';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addp").click(function(){
      $(".products").after(tbl);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see the point of adding elements using jquery when you're using angularjs. Try populating the products rows using ng-repeat by binding it to an array of product objects. You can add new objects to the said array dynamically and the view will be rendered automatically

Comment: here we don't know  how many product to be added early, and I don't know how to do that , show some code plz

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear and assuming you want to mimic similar behavior in angularjs (dynamically add products rows), here's an example on how you can do this.

Render your products using an ng-repeat by iterating over a `products` array.

```
<html  ng-app="MyApp">
<head>... </head>
<body ng-controller="ProductsController">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr class="products" ng-repeat="p in products track by $index">
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="number" ng-model="p.qty"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="number" ng-model="p.rate"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l">{{p.qty * p.rate}}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="tg-yw4l">
               <button class="addp" ng-click="addProduct()">Add New Product</button>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Add objects to `products` array dynamically.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('ProductsController', 
   function($scope) {
       // this array is bound to view
       $scope.products= [{qty:0, rate:0}];

       // this function is bound to the ng-click event of the button
       $scope.addProducts = function() {
           $scope.products.push({qty:0, rate:0});
       };
   }
);
```